# Embed SSL keys inside application

Tags: c++, c, openssl

Would it be possible to embed the private and public key for a simple server application into it through the C/C++ APIs? Preferably without hacking the entire OpenSSL library first.

And by embed I mean by passing either something like a string or a char* to the API instead of reading directly from a file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `d2i_X509()` function to directly convert a DER-encoded certificate from an `unsigned char *` buffer into an X509 object:

```
const unsigned char cert_DER[] = /* ... */;

const unsigned char *p = cert_DER;
X509 *cert_X509 = d2i_X509(NULL, &p, sizeof cert_DER);
```

There are similar `d2i_*()` functions for other OpenSSL objects, like keys - eg. `d2i_RSAPrivateKey()`.

Comment: I ended up using this method and a combination of 'objcopy'

Answer (score 3):

In general (not limited to `openssl`), when I find a need to encode something like a file into memory where I prefer not to have to `open`/`read` or `mmap` it, I usually use `objcopy` (provided I have access to GNU `binutils` for the given project).  It's terribly effective.

For example:

```
objcopy --input binary --output elf32-i386 --binary-architecture i386 resource.img resource.o
```

`objcopy` creates object code containing the data in `resource.img` and creates symbols called `_binary_resource_img_start` and `_binary_data_txt_end` (and ...`length`).  I can make `extern` declarations of these variables and take their address in order to find the resource in memory.  Voilà!

Comment: This looks very promising, happen to know how to do this for x86_64? I got some issues while trying so myself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You use `BIO_new_mem_buf` to create an input `BIO` for the read routines, and then call the appropriate `PEM_read_bio_*` functions to extract the keys and certificates.

```
BIO *in = BIO_new_mem_buf(pkey, pkey_len);
EVP_PKEY *ep = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(in, ...);

BIO *in = BIO_new_mem_buf(certs, cert_len);
X509 *x = PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX(in, ...);
```